# Splitting string by spaces difficulty

Tags: c++, string, iterator, getline, istringstream

My code is working except for one problem, when I run it it doesn't seem to return the first string.

```
    string text;
    cin >> text;
    getline(cin ,text);
    istringstream  iss(text);
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
            istream_iterator<string>(),
            ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```

So if my input was, `bf "ing" filename`, it will only output:

```
"ing" 
filename
```

I want it so it can output the whole line like so:

```
bf 
"ing"
filename
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to have the entire line printed from parsing the string passed to `std::istringstream` you should remove first reading a separate word, i.e., remove the line

```
cin >> text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of

`cin >> text;` .

That one consumes the first word of your input, reads it into `text`, and then you discard it by overwriting `text` in the next line.